# PHP Mysql Case insensitive table select

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to detect if a table in the database already exists. However, the following code I've written seems to be case-sensitive.  If a table name is Test and $name = TEST. The code below will not be true. Is there any way to make this case INSENSITIVE? Or perhaps there is a more efficient way?

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$name'")) == 1) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Why not just change the value of $name to appropriate case using strtolower(),strtoupper(), or ucwords()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers but it seems I've answered my own question. I'm just going to store all tables as lowercase using strtolower()

And then:

```
$LowerName = strtolower($name);
if( mysql_num_rows( mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$LowerName'")) == 1)
{
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you check the value of the **lower_case_table_names** system variable.  The default value is assigned on the basis of your OS:

- 0 - UNIX/Linux
- 1 - Windows
- 2 - Mac

According to the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html):

> - 0 - Table and database names are stored on disk using the
>   lettercase specified in the CREATE TABLE or CREATE DATABASE statement.
>   Name comparisons are case sensitive. You should not set this variable
>   to 0 if you are running MySQL on a system that has case-insensitive
>   file names (such as Windows or Mac OS X). If you force this variable
>   to 0 with --lower-case-table-names=0 on a case-insensitive file system
>   and access MyISAM tablenames using different lettercases, index
>   corruption may result.
> - 1 - Table names are stored in lowercase on disk
>   and name comparisons are not case sensitive. MySQL converts all table
>   names to lowercase on storage and lookup. This behavior also applies
>   to database names and table aliases.
> - 2 - Table and database names are
>   stored on disk using the lettercase specified in the CREATE TABLE or
>   CREATE DATABASE statement, but MySQL converts them to lowercase on
>   lookup. Name comparisons are not case sensitive. This works only on
>   file systems that are not case sensitive! InnoDB table names are
>   stored in lowercase, as for lower_case_table_names=1.

Of course, you can alter the value of **lower_case_table_names**, but you would need to export/import your data in order for it to affect your current database tables.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, can't be done using that syntax.  You'll have to do something like:

```
SELECT `TABLE_NAME`
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES`
WHERE `TABLE_CATALOG` IS NULL
AND `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'yourdatabasename'
AND `TABLE_NAME` LIKE 'yourtablename'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$name = "table_name";
$result = mysql_list_tables("mydb");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {
    if (strtolower(mysql_tablename($result, $i)) == strtolower($name)) {
        echo "Table detected";

    }
}
```